# Cant load css in my templates in django 1.5

Tags: python, css, django

```
/project_root/
manage.py
    /project/
        /static/
            /css/
            /js/
            /img/
        /media/
        settings.py
        urls.py
```

This is my folder structure. My settings.py is like :

This is my settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
 #  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'employee.views.index'),    
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

tempates:

```
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/logo48.png" rel="SHORTCUT ICON" />
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

In the view source I can see :

```
<link href="/static/css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="/static/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="/static/css/fixes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

But css are not loading in my template files. Please guide me .

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial?

Comment: did you do `./manage.py collectstatic` ? also ; what looks like your `PROJECT_ROOT` value ?

Comment: @FoxMask in my code: PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave`STATIC_ROOT` empty.

Add this in `STATICFILES_DIRS`:

```
os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')
```

Make sure the upper code contains: `/project_root/project/static`

In urls.py remove these useless lines:

```
+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Run `./manage.py collectstatic`

Should work.

**Edit:**

Since you have already done `{% load static %}` you don't need to do `{{ STATIC_URL }}/..`

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

Please note this answer doesn't apply if you are using the internal django development server.

Have you added an alias for `/static/` in your Apache setup? If not, any calls to that folder will result in a 404 error, meaning your CSS won't load. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / "/path/to/project/project/wsgi.py"

    DocumentRoot "/path/to/project"
    <Directory "/path/to/project">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ "/path/to/project/media/"
    <Directory "/path/to/project/media/">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ "/path/to/project/static/"
    <Directory "/path/to/project/static/">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```